# Using array prototyped methods in Underscore.js

Tags: underscore.js

Help me please solve my problem. I'm using `underscore.js` lib and I have [a snippet](http://jsbin.com/ubihac/edit#source) that demonstrates what problem I have:

```
var a = [4, 3, 2, 1];
var b = _(a).select(function(el){ return el>1; }).push(6);
console.log("b: "+b);
// b: 4
var c = _(a).select(function(el){ return el>1; });
c.push(6);
console.log("c: "+c);
// c: [4, 3, 2, 6]
```

What is going on? Why `select()` function returns something strange - like an object with integer keys. But when we put results of `select()` we can use array native methods again. Why? What is it?
I know that we can use native array methods inside of `chain()`, but snippet results is really strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the push method returns the index at which the value was inserted into the array.
For more details see the [push method documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)
The `b` variable is the same as:

```
var c = _(a).select(function(el){ return el>1; });
c = c.push(6);
console.log("c: "+c);
// c: 4
```

Comment: It returns new length of array (c). Thanks! But it's so... length is a property, what was the reason to return it... strange :)